Can OP in the Staging Ground see the edit history?
I want to make several edits to a Staging Ground history in order to show the OP some important things about how we expect questions to be written. It's clearly too much to take in all at once. Currently I'm just making an edit to format the code properly (and remove a ton of irrelevant blank lines - I don't really know how they got there). I'd like to make further edits to do things like removing noise, further editing the code to a proper MRE (because I see the problem and am able to do so), etc.
(Note: the question is a duplicate, but I want to illustrate some important things about how to write questions.)
I know that the Staging Ground offers a feature to turn the edit summary into a comment. Does OP have access to see the corresponding edit? I'd like to make it possible to follow along with my changes as I described them.

Might be even harder than you expect. Does the system not batch up all contiguous edits made by a user within 5 minutes into a single edit?

It does, but I'm prepared to deal with that.

Noble intention from you, but "in this case", you'll probably be wasting your time, I would think...: The Asker had already been asked by a first Reviewer to format their Code properly, they did check SO and their Question 7h later, but didn't take any action at all, and your Edit was 44h after the first Review, but the Asker had still not reacted at all in all this time and never tried to improve/edit their Question...

AFAIK yes the author should be able to access the edit history but some parts (e.g. which reviewers voted to close) may be redacted (it should be available under the same link where it is also available to reviewers). However, I don't know whether authors are notified about their questions being edited and there are definitely cases where the author doesn't really look at the edit or similar.

@chivracq Point well taken. I'll give up on this project, but I think this Q is still useful for Meta.

Well, the Asker must have gotten some Notif from your Edit + Comment + Dupe-Hammering as they checked SO 3h later, but still no reaction/follow-up in their Question (Qt) in SG. // Current Qt useful for 'Meta' = Yes, sure... // Side-note: Pretty strange btw to see that the Asker created their Qt on 2024-10-20 23:30:30, while according to their Profile, they only registered on 2024-10-21 01:05:54, = 1.5 hours later...! One of the 2 timestamps must be incorrect...

@chivracq I think accounts can exist before they're "registered", because of how the account creation process works now.
